# Get product list which have special price for particular customer group

Tags: magento

I want to display list of product in cms page that contain special price for customer group only.
for example , if i have 5 product with special price in group-one then that cms page only show that 5 products.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you attempting to restrict products to show only for a specific customer group?

Comment: yes, i want to show only product available to those group with special price in cms page.